# How does flyway sort version numbers?

Tags: flyway

If we have migrations like:

```
V1_6__six.sql
V1_7__seven.sql
V1_8__eight.sql
V1_9__nine.sql
```

What should we use for the next version?

If we use `V1_10` will that come after `V1__9`? Or would we need to prefix the single digit version numbers with a `0`?

Really the question is: are version numbers sorted numerically or alphabetically?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In one word: numerically. As would be expected for a number.

Comment: i'd like to reuse the 'sorting part'. which file should i look at?

Comment: @Axel-Fontaine - that doesn't seem to be the case exactly, unless I misunderstand that:

`1.1.015   | blah1                             |                     | Pending |
 1.2.001   | blah2                             |                     | Pending |
 1.2.1.001 | blah3                             |                     | Pending |
 1.2.1.002 | blah4                             |                     | Pending |
 1.2.002   | blah7                             |                     | Pending |
 1.2.003   | blah8                             |                     | Pending |`

Comment: My format is the form: V1.2_001__blah2.sql and  V1.2.1_002__blah4.sql.  Looks like leading zeros are dropped when sorting.

Comment: I guess I'll just use 3 digits consistently to avoid the issue.

Comment: Why I can't find this information in official docs? https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migrations#naming

Answer (score 7):

For a definitive answer on how the sorting happens, you can refer to the code. This [test](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/de7e2f184c5be7e31f4d8357e99a72c6f1428377/flyway-core/src/test/java/org/flywaydb/core/api/MigrationVersionSmallTest.java) is especially helpful.

```
@Test
public void testNumber() {
    final MigrationVersion a1 = MigrationVersion.fromVersion("1.2.13.3");
    final MigrationVersion a2 = MigrationVersion.fromVersion("1.2.3.3");
    assertTrue(a1.compareTo(a2) > 0);
}

@Test
public void testLength1() {
    final MigrationVersion a1 = MigrationVersion.fromVersion("1.2.1.3");
    final MigrationVersion a2 = MigrationVersion.fromVersion("1.2.1");
    assertTrue(a1.compareTo(a2) > 0);
}

@Test
public void testLength2() {
    final MigrationVersion a1 = MigrationVersion.fromVersion("1.2.1");
    final MigrationVersion a2 = MigrationVersion.fromVersion("1.2.1.1");
    assertTrue(a1.compareTo(a2) < 0);
}

@Test
public void leadingZeroes() {
    final MigrationVersion v1 = MigrationVersion.fromVersion("1.0");
    final MigrationVersion v2 = MigrationVersion.fromVersion("001.0");
    assertTrue(v1.compareTo(v2) == 0);
    assertTrue(v1.equals(v2));
    assertEquals(v1.hashCode(), v2.hashCode());
}
```

Comment: I don't see this test anywhere in the master branch, but would love to know that the ordering is done the same way still. Any idea where the test/ path got refactored to?

Comment: The `org.flywaydb.core.api.MigrationVersion.compareTo` method also explains the algorithm quite well.